# Where does aero wheels noise come from?

Tags: wheels, aerodynamics

One time I hear someone said, with satisfaction, that his aero wheels sound awesome. I wonder where does the noise come from, is it because you ride so fast the pushed air makes the noise or is it just noise of carbon fairing vibration?

Comment: I always thought the *horrible* sound they make was due to the cavernous empty space inside the things. Of course I might think it was an awesome noise if I owned some :-)

Comment: It comes from his head.  If it were the mark of a cheap wheel it would sound annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carbon wheels will have a different sound die to handling vibrations differently than aluminum. Has nothing to do with aerodynamics.